# Moving Url.Action into Jquery/JS? (MVC Web App)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

Environment: ASP.NET 3.5, MVC 2 Web App, in the View file Index.aspx

I have the following jqGrid (excerpt of code):

```
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("GridData") %>',
        datatype: 'json',
```

This is in an inline JS function called populateGrid. I need to move this function out of the View and into its own JS. In order to do this I need to store the <%= Url.Action("GridData") %> as a variable in javascript.

This:

```
var griddata = <%= Url.Action("GridData") %>;
```

doesn't appear to work. I am wondering what syntax I should use and/or how I can do this. The populateGrid function is going to be called by multiple pages so that is why it is being put into a .js file.

Comment: Where are you putting the 'var griddata = ...' code? is it inside another function/closure? and what is the context of the $("#list").jqGrid();

Comment: under $(document).ready(function() {});

Comment: jqGrid is just to define the JQGrid, it has a lot of properties so i only pasted the first few. It's in a populateGrid() function which is also called under the $(document).ready

Comment: (and "list" is a table on the page.. just to clarify)

Answer (score 0):

Throw in some quotes:

```
var griddata = '<%= Url.Action("GridData") %>';
```

Should solve your specific problem there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem your having is that the griddata variable is local to the $(document).ready closure. you need to decleare it outside that scope to be global or pass it to the js scope. So to make it global you would do:

```
var griddata = ... // this outside the function/closure

$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Now, polluting the global namespace with all your config variables may not be the best method to pass this type of data around.... you could create a config object to hold all you config vars (with defaults and all) in your master page, so it gets correctly initialized for every page... something like:

```
var myAppConfig = {
   gridData : '<%= Url.Action("xxxx") %>',
   otherConfig : 'some more configuration here'
};
```

then you can use it in your js files